# Cannot call Custom Helper Array in Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel

**HR_Helper.php**

```
class HR_Helper{
    public static $Grade = array(1,2,3,4);
    public $work_shift = array("Work Shift","Regular Work Hours","Part Time");
    public $Salutation = array('Mr.','Miss','Mrs.','Ms.','Dr.'); 
    public $leave_types = array('Sick Leave','Maternity Leaves','Casual Leaves','Annual Leaves');    
    public $leave_status = array(0,1,2);        
}
```

Now i call these helper array in controller like that...

**hrController.php**

```
HR_Helper::Grade;
```

but it throw the following error

```
Class 'App\Http\Controllers\HR_H' not found
```

I also add these Helper in controller like that.. (`use HR_R;`)

HR_R helper is also added in the `app.php` -> `aliases` like 
`'HR_H' => App\Helpers\HR_Helper::class`.

But it still not working...

Comment: where did you put your class helper file?

Comment: In app.php have you added to your provider?

Comment: have you added to your autoload?

Comment: Otherwise following this guide line for automatically registering your helpers class if you have a lot.